# Exception in callback of async function: Error: Future resolved more than once

Tags: node.js, meteor, futuretask, node-fibers, npm-request

Hi guys I try to use [proxy-verifier NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxy-verifier) in Meteor like below:

```
import ProxyVerifier from 'proxy-verifier';

// this is my method call on server startup
Jobs.find().forEach((job) => {
 Meteor.call("checkProxy", job.proxy, (error, result) => {
  if (error) {
   console.log("error: " + error);
  } else {
   console.log("result: " + result); // result is true or false
   let inc;
   inc = result ? 1 : -1;
   Jobs.update({
    _id: job._id
   }, {
    $inc: {
     count: inc
    }
   });
  }
 });
});

// this is my method
checkProxy(proxy) {
 this.unblock();

 let syncTestProtocol = Meteor.wrapAsync(ProxyVerifier.testProtocol);
 let testResult;
 try {
  testResult = syncTestProtocol(proxy);
  return testResult.ok;
 } catch (error) {
  return false;
 }
}
```

It's works well but sometimes (maybe on check some proxy) it return below exception:

```
I20160724-07:48:18.391(4.5)? Exception in callback of async function: Error: Future resolved more than once
I20160724-07:48:18.391(4.5)?     at Object.Future.return (/home/username/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.5_1.emd1tx++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:261:10)
I20160724-07:48:18.391(4.5)?     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/username/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.5_1.emd1tx++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:349:16)
I20160724-07:48:18.391(4.5)?     at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:110:1)
I20160724-07:48:18.392(4.5)? Exception in callback of async function: Error: Future resolved more than once
I20160724-07:48:18.392(4.5)?     at Object.Future.return (/home/username/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.5_1.emd1tx++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:261:10)
I20160724-07:48:18.393(4.5)?     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/username/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.5_1.emd1tx++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:349:16)
I20160724-07:48:18.393(4.5)?     at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:110:1)
```

I used `Meteor.wrapAsync` in `checkProxy` method is it related to this? Please guide me how to find and fix this issue.